# Solspace Tracker - by member group?

Tags: solspace

Is there a way to view stats broken per member group or individual member?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that's not possible. Tracker tracks entry views, but doesn't collect information about the visiting user. Google Analytics or something open source such as [Piwik](https://piwik.org/) could provide that kind of functionality.